# how to check properly formatted email id

Tags: javascript, html

```
     <script>  
     window.onload = function()
    {
document.getElementById('btn').disabled=true;
function bar() 
{

  var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
 var d=document.getElementById('uid').value;
if( re.test(d))
    document.getElementById('btn').disabled=false;
}
};
</script>
<button type="button" id="btn" >Log-in</button>
 <label for="uid">User Id</label><input type="text" name="uid" id="uid" onKeyUp="return bar()" />
```

I am trying to check whether the email id entered in the textbox `uid` is properly formatted or not and if the email id given matches the expression it will simply enable the `btn` button. when i execute the following nothing happen the button stays disabled if even the email id is formatted properly. HELP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a scope issue. The `bar()` function is defined within the `window.onload` function, and therefore is not accessible from where you try to call it (the inline `onkeyup` handler).

Move the function into the global scope:

```
function bar() {
    ...
}

window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('btn').disabled = true;
};
```

---

Or better still, attach the event inside the `window.onload` and remove the inline `onkeyup` completely.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b9BjX/2/)

```
function bar() {
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    var d = document.getElementById('uid').value;
    document.getElementById('btn').disabled = !re.test(d);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var btn = document.getElementById('btn').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("uid").onkeyup = bar;
};
```

Using this way, `bar` can be defined either in the `onload` or in the global scope, both will work. Also, I changed the logic in `bar()`. It will now re-disable if you type a valid email, then make it invalid.

Comment: will this enable the button when the value of the textbox changes ?